# Unable to login on KindleForPC when using Tor+Privoxy

Tags: proxy, amazon-web-services, tor, kindle

Amazon is blocked on my network, I use Tor to access some sites.

If I use Kindle with default settings, it reports unable to access Amazon and asks me to config network.

I installed and configured Privoxy, it connects to Tor by SOCKS5 on port 9050 and provides an HTTP proxy on port 8118.

When I configure Kindle to use proxy on 127.0.0.1:8118 it doesn't report network error anymore. But when I go to Options>Register, it opens a dialog where I should provide login-password, but this dialog is empty. All I have is a dropdown to select from where I wanna login, with many Amazon domains to choose.

Either domain I choose, the dialog remains empty and there's no input to type login and password.

Any idea now to make it work?

Comment: This only works if an application is designed to respect the proxy settings of the PC.  Based on what you describe this particular application does not.

Comment: Do you mean that it's ignoring its proxy settings and trying to access Amazon directly? This would be a bug.

Comment: As a programmer you have to design your program to use the proxy settings of an OS, the fact it does or does not do that, is not technically a bug.

Comment: That's sad, tnx :(